# folder redirection not working

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, folder-redirection

My domain had a conflict with KB3159398, which resulted in the forced folder redirection Group Policy, to stop working a few week ago.  When the clients were restarted, this started migrating all the server redirected folders to the local drive.   We've since un-install the offending update and most have migrated back to the server.  However, a few cleints don't want to move back.  They give the following error in event viewer:

> "Folder "Documents" has to be redirected.  Redirection options =
>   0x9021.  Parent folder = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}". 
>   Path = "\xxx.local\users\RedirectedFolders\%USERNAME%\My Documents". 
>   Group = s-1-1-0."

Any ideas to get these back over to the redirect these back to the server?

Comment: Can you be specific about which update you are talking about?  Have you tried to push a group poiicy update to help the clients that didn't fix themselfs?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Yeah sure - I'll get the details.  I didn't put the MS update details in as I didn't think it was important.  That issue has been resolved by uninstalling the offending update.  The problem now is how to folder redirection back to the server where it belongs.

Comment: The offending update is kb3159398. like i said this update has now been un-install from all clients and servers

Comment: Understanding the entire problem, understanding which patch caused the problem, allows for independent research resulting in the community submitting an answer to your question.

Comment: Have you verified the read permissions on the GPO?  I had to remove this specific update from a network for different reasons, so got some experience, with this particular gem. I am particularly interested in the read permissions for `Authenticated Users` group  and `Domain Computers` group.  In my case a replacement client could be created in less then 5 minutes, so I am guessing, you want a solution that fixes those clients.

Comment: In Domain Computers Group, Authenticated users have read-only privileges.  Out of 80 machines, only 10 still are still having trouble migrating folder redirection back to the server (They display error "Redirection options=0x9021")

Comment: Have you tried to use a different user on those 10 machine?

Comment: No, but I can.  We have 1 user per a laptop, no shared machines.

Comment: Just logged on with my user on a problem machine and it looks local so could be a machne specific issue.